# homogeneous subalgebra of a Lie superalgebra

Tags: lie-algebras, graded-algebras, superalgebra, free-lie-algebra, lie-superalgebras

In the case of Lie superalgebras which are defined as $L=L_{\bar{0}} \oplus L_{\bar{1}}$, I am a bit confused about the term "homogeneous subalgebra". Does it mean that the subalgebra which is generated by, for instance, $A \subseteq X_{\bar{0}}$, where $ X_{\bar{0}}$ are generators of degree zero is a homogeneous subalgebra? Thank you for your time.